# How do I put a image inside of every brick on the brick texture?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

I have a question, basically my question is this :, so I have a brick texture [image] and I have a picture of a light bulb, and I want to put it so that the picture is inside of every brick, but when I put a texture inside of the diffuse node, it just appears over every brick [image], how can I make it so that the light bulb appears individually in each brick? Thanks

Comment: I will attempt to answer this later, but just out of curiosity - why do you want a picture of a lightbulb in every brick? Sounds a bit random, doesn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## It is not possible to map image textures using a Brick Texture node

For texture placemanet you need texture coordinates. Brick texture outputs only colors. So it is not possible to map any images to the colors of the brick texture.

## However, you can manipulate texture coordinates using Math nodes

Texture coordinates are only sort of gradients going in some direction from -∞ to + ∞ and you can manipulate them with all sorts of math functions:

[image]

So using various maths functions you can construct the same brick pattern out of
the texture coordinate gradients and use that to map any image you wish in the same pattern:

[image]

[image]

Comment: That’s a very complicated set of nodes - please can you elaborate on how that works?

Comment: Absolute function makes negative values positive, then modulo repeats a range of values that is then normalized to go from 0 to 1, all values that were origanally negative are inverted by using a negative number in the modulo operation, a gap is added by multiplying the values and then clipping them with 'less than' node. The math is not that complicated one just needs to follow the nodes and see what they do. The key idea is to use modulo math function to repeat a range of values, in this case 0 to 1 in both x and y(or U and V) axis.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quick way to do this.
[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]
[image: image 3]
[image: image 4]
[image: image 5]